# static constexpr function different than global?

Tags: c++, static, constexpr

I cannot understand why static constexpr behaves differently then global constexpr. What am I doing wrong? Compiler error is not particularly helpful:

```
prog.cpp:20:17: error: ‘static constexpr int Bar::foo(const char*)’ called in a constant expression
B = Bar::foo(s)
             ^
prog.cpp:20:17: error: enumerator value for ‘B’ is not an integer constant
```

code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int foo(const char* v)
{
    return v[0];
}

struct Bar
{
    static constexpr int foo(const char* v)
    {
        return v[0];
    }

    static constexpr const char* s = "abc";

    enum
    {
        A = ::foo(s),
        B = Bar::foo(s)
    };
};

int main()
{
    int a[Bar::A];
    a[0] = Bar::A;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because the `enum` is part of the class declaration, whereas the definitions of the functions inside the class are logically deferred until after the class declaration.  This means that as far as the `enum` is concerned, it can't see the definition of `B::foo`, and therefore it can't use a call to it as a constant expression.  You can see this by putting the `enum` after the class:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int foo(const char* v)
{
    return v[0];
}

struct Bar
{
    static constexpr int foo(const char* v)
    {
        return v[0];
    }

    static constexpr const char* s = "abc";
};

enum Enum
{
    A = ::foo(Bar::s),
    B = Bar::foo(Bar::s)
};
```

which gives no error.

Comment: Unfortunately, this causes the enum to not be part of the class. [But you can still do that.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/838e6daf5c9186c9)

Comment: What about initialisation of static constants? My intuition tells me they are done quite late. Compiler error is different: "field initializer is not constant".